# SpTBX: how to make "<< >>" buttons inside tab set

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

`TSpTbxTabSet/TSpTbxTabControl` demo has such a feature. buttons don't disappear when tabset shrinks and stay at right side of tabset.

[image: feature]

How to make such buttons near/inside the tabset?

Comment: http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/support.htm#10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area that the tabs are added to is essentially a SpTBX toolbar, so you can add additional items. If you examine the source for the SpTBX overview demo, it shows all you need to do is add a TSpTBXRightAlignSpacerItem and then the additional buttons (Tab left, Tab right, Tab close) as shown in the screen shot below

[image: Editing SpTBXTabControl]

For more information on the control I would suggest reading [tsptbxrightalignspaceritem](http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/items.htm#tsptbxrightalignspaceritem) on the Silverpoint docs